# Twilight - How many vampires have powers?

Tags: twilight

**In the *Twilight* books, how many vampires have special powers?**

In the novella - *The Short Second Life of Bree Tanner* - Riley tells the newborns that only about 2% of vampires have special powers. At first I thought this was accurate, but then I started thinking about it; it makes sense that the Volturi have special powers - they're the elite vampire police, of course they're made up of the special vampires - but more than half of the Cullens have special powers, which seems really rare.

Did Riley just lie to the newborns to discourage them from thinking they had powers? Or was he correct?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem so odd to me, and in part because this was the reason that the Volturi were sointerested in the Cullens. Remember, apparently the manifestation of powers I'd due to certain personality traits or skills that the person has as a human and for the most part, each of the Cullens has a back story that is quite remarkable.